# Php mail not sending mails

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send mail with the  following php script but the mail is not going through ....the  script runs to the  end but no mail is sent, 
What is  the  best way to debug if the  mail is being sent?

```
$link = $this->db_connection();
        $enc_password = md5($password);

        //checking if the username is available in the table
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT concat(users.title,' ',users.f_name,' ',users.s_name,' ',users.o_name) as fullname, user_id,user_name,role_id,status from users WHERE email='$emailusername' or user_name='$emailusername' and password='$enc_password'");
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        $count_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $base_url = $this->url();
        if ($count_row == 1) {
            if ($password === "123456") {

                //set the random id length 
                $random_id_length = 10;
                $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                //generate a random id encrypt it and store it in $rnd_id 
                $rnd_id = crypt(uniqid($today, 1));
                //to remove any slashes that might have come 
                $rnd_id = strip_tags(stripslashes($rnd_id));

                //Removing any . or / and reversing the string 
                $rnd_id = str_replace(".", "", $rnd_id);
                $rnd_id = strrev(str_replace("/", "", $rnd_id));

                //finally I take the first 10 characters from the $rnd_id 
                $random_key = substr($rnd_id, 0, $random_id_length);

                $email = $user_data['email'];
                $username = $user_data['username'];
                $user_id = $user_data['user_id'];
                $full_name = $user_data['fullname'];
                $headers = "From: webmaster@emarps.org" . "\r\n" .
                        "CC: harrisdindisamuel@gmail.com";
                $subject = "Reset User Account Password";
                // the message
                $msg = '
                                                                           ---------------------
                                                                                Hey :' . $full_name . '!
                                                                                    <fieldset>
                                                                                We currently received a request for resetting your EMARPS  ACCOUNT Password. You can reset your   Personal Account Password 
                                                                                through the link below:
                                                                                <hr>
                                                                                ------------------------
                                                                                Please click this link to activate your account:<a href="' . $base_url . 'resetpassword.php?uq=/' . $random_key . '">Reset</a>


                                                                                ------------------------ ';
                ;

                // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
                // $msg = wordwrap($msg, 70);
                // send email
                mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);

            }
```

What is the best way to determine if the mail function is working/ if the  mail is going through?

Comment: First, have a look at what [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) returns to see if the function "is working". (Should return `true`.)

Comment: What soft is installed for sending emails on your environment?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple if statement:

```
if(mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo 'Mail send!';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

You can only check if the mailserver has excepted the mail not if the mail was really delivered you can check that case only in your mailserver (mailq) or with a return mail address where all bounce mails come to and you check that inbox. Its a bit more complicated.